# Obtain combined standard errors of main and interaction term

Tags: r, interaction, standard-error

How could I get the combined  standard error of main  and interaction term? In model1 I wish to get combined estimates for progAcademic and progAcademic:math.

I have provided sample data below:

```
df <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/poisson_sim.csv")
df <- within(df, {
prog <- factor(prog, levels=1:3, labels=c("General", "Academic", "Vocational"))
id <- factor(id)
})
mdel1 <- glm(num_awards ~ prog + math + prog*math, family="poisson", data=df)
```

Comment: What do you mean combined estimates? You don't usually combine estimates in this setup. It'd be better to reestimate the model without interactions.

Comment: @user30035, I was after combined standard error model output (see my edit) .I have two standards errors (one for progAcademic and one for progAcademic:math). Obviously I could not add the two as I could with estimates. In Stata one uses "lincom" to obtain this output

Comment: I usually do these things 'by hand' using vcov and matrix multiplication but I think the contrast package is what you're looking for.